# Issue while installing docker in ubuntu server

Tags: docker

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) 
   linux-image-extra-virtual
```

getting error

```
demo@demo:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-extra-4.15.0-29-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-extra-4.15.0-29-generic'
```

why I am getting this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: Hello and welocme AskUbuntu! Can you try to execute `sudo apt -f install` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`? Try to refresh the package cache with `sudo apt update`, too.

Comment: tried all these still the same error